# Removing the corner of a box outline in SVG (or any part of any element in SVG)

Tags: svg, mask, clip-path

I'm trying to advance beyond the basics of **SVG** and create an image which involves masking or clipping. However I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

I understand that I can use `<mask>` to leave parts of the image visible and remove everything else.

What I cannot see - either with `<clip-path>` or with `<mask>` - is how to remove parts of the image and leave everything else visible.

Here is the beginning of an image below:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 420 420">

<defs>

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

rect:nth-of-type(1) {
fill: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

rect, g rect:nth-of-type(1) {
stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
stroke-width: 10;
fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

]]></style>
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="420" height="420" />
<rect x="21" y="99" width="300" height="300" rx="15" ry="15" />

<g transform="rotate(-45 50 50)">
<rect x="-100" y="240" width="355" height="90" />
</g>

</svg>
```

What is the correct approach to removing the top-right corner of the box, beneath the 45-degree slanted rectangle, so that the dark red rectangle shows through from below?

**N.B.** I do mean *remove* and not just hide. I know I can `fill` the rectangle and it will hide the box-corner beneath.

---

## Update 1

I have come up with "a solution" using `<clip-path>` which looks great:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 420 420">

<defs>

<clipPath id="clip-corner">
<path d="M0,76 L274,76 L224,126 L306,209 L355,160 L355,420 L0,420 L0,76" />
</clipPath>

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

rect:nth-of-type(1) {
fill: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

rect:nth-of-type(2) {
clip-path: url(#clip-corner);
}

rect, g rect:nth-of-type(1) {
stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
stroke-width: 10;
fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

]]></style>
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="420" height="420" />
<rect x="21" y="99" width="300" height="300" rx="15" ry="15" />
<g transform="rotate(-45 50 50)">
<rect x="-100" y="240" width="355" height="90" />
</g>

</svg>
```

But... the problem is, this is how I did it. By drawing the following `clip-path`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 420 420">

<defs>

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

rect:nth-of-type(1) {
fill: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

rect {
stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
stroke-width: 10;
fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

path {
stroke: #ffff00;
fill: none;
}

]]></style>
</defs>

<rect x="0" y="0" width="420" height="420" />
<path d="M0,76 L274,76 L224,126 L306,209 L355,160 L355,420 L0,420 L0,76" /> 
<rect x="21" y="99" width="300" height="300" rx="15" ry="15" />

</svg>
```

That's not how you're supposed to do it, is it?

Answer (score 1):

1. In a mask, everything that should be visible should be white: make the background white. Everything that should be invisble should be black: make the slanted rectangle plus a wide enough stroke black.
2. Reuse the basic shapes with `<use>`, so that you only need to edit them in one place. Define them within `<defs>` and make sure no style is applied to them. Instead, apply the style to the `<use>` elements.

```css
mask use:first-child {
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

mask use:last-child {
    stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    stroke-width: 30;
}

.filled {
    fill: rgb(191, 0, 0);
}

.stroked {
    stroke: rgb(255,255,255);
    stroke-width: 10;
}

.masked {
     mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 420 420">

  <defs>

    <rect id="back" x="0" y="0" width="420" height="420" />
    <rect id="slanted" transform="rotate(-45 50 50)"
          x="-100" y="240" width="355" height="90" />

    <mask id="mask">
      <use xlink:href="#back" />
      <use xlink:href="#slanted" />
    </mask>

  </defs>

  <use class="filled" xlink:href="#back" />

  <rect class="filled stroked masked"
        x="21" y="99" width="300" height="300" rx="15" ry="15" />

  <use class="filled stroked" xlink:href="#slanted" />

</svg>
```